# Accepting a Spring Data REST URI in custom controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data Rest webmvc application that I'd like to add some custom functionality to for batch operations.

I've created a controller, and blended it into the uri namespace, but I'd like for it to be able to accept URI's like the custom `/search` queries do, rather than simply an ID.

I have tried registering a custom `<String, Long>` converter (my entity has a `Long` ID type, but that seems to get ignored. Is there any way to configure my controller such that it adopts that behavior from the auto-implemented SDR controllers?

Even if there is some sort of method I can call that will auto-resolve a URI to an entity, that would work just as well (as I can then simply accept a `String` in my controller)

Here's where I'm at.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    //irrelevant code omitted

    @Bean
    public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter() {
        DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService> dc = new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(mvcConversionService());
        return dc;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
          registry.addConverter(String.class, Long.class, testConverter());
    }

    @Bean 
    Converter<String, Long> testConverter() {
        return new Converter<String, Long>() {

            @Override
            public Long convert(String source) {
                //this code does _not_ get run at any point
                if (source.indexOf('/') == -1) { return Long.parseLong(source); }

                source = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                Long id = Long.parseLong(source);

                return id;
            }   
        };
    }
}
```

SDR Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = { HypermediaType.HAL })
public class CustomRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
      RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
      config.setBasePath("/api");
      config.exposeIdsFor(ApplicationMembership.class);
      return config;
    }


}
```

And my (contrived) controller:

ApplicationType is one of my entities that are correctly managed by SDR/repository magic

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("applications/special")
public class ApplicationExtensionController {
    @RequestMapping("a")
    public ResponseEntity<?> reply(@RequestParam("type") ApplicationType type) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(type.getIcon(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I've looked around quite a bit but can't quite manage to make anything work. When I create a `<String, ApplicationType>` converter that utilizes the repository, it also does not get called, as the DomainClassConverter just calls its underlying `<String, Long>` converter (which obviously fails, as it cannot correctly parse out `types/1` into a long.

Appreciate the help!

Forgot to mention

- Spring Data Rest 2.4.0
- Spring HATEOAS 0.19.0
- Spring 4.2.1

Using JPA repositories

Comment: Have you tried annotating your Controller with @RepositoryRestController? In fact, I had no problems auto-getting SDR entities from PathVariables in regular controllers, but then, I'm using Spring Boot and it includes some autoconfiguration.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks Ilya!

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev Unfortunately no dice. I'd like to be able to query it like so `GET domain.com/api/applications/batch/removeType?type=types/7` but it's still throwing an unable to convert error.

Comment: Your URL looks strange, that '/' in param value might be a problem. Why don't you try `applications/batch/removeType/7`, that is, make `type` a `@PathVariable`? Also, is `type` field a key for your entity? It should be for Spring to autoconvert it.

Comment: I am looking to replicate the functionality of the SDR `/entity/search` controller methods, which accept queries like so `GET /api/applications/search/hasType?type=types/7`. The idea is to make interactions with the API similar in all cases. Not that it would be impossible to fetch just the ID, but the goal is that I can configure the controller to natively accept URI's. Thus path variables are out of the question, as they add in an inconsistency when compared to SDR's built-in capabilities.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apparently that logic (String->URI->Entity) is implemented in a few private methods of `RepositorySearchController` (see `executeQueryMethod` and `prepareUris`), so there's no easy way to get it in custom controllers. You can try creating your own argument resolver with Spring HATEOAS. Look into how `@BackendId` resolver is implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, I was on the right track with adding a converter, unfortunately I was doing it in the wrong configuration method.

I was able to get the desired functionality by moving my `testConverter()` bean to the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` extension config class and then adding

```
@Override
public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService service) {
    service.addConverter(testConverter());
}
```

And working as intended. I feel a bit silly now for throwing that in the wrong spot in the first place, but hopefully this will help someone else out!

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. What is `mvcConversionService()`?

Comment: See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#mvcConversionService-- It is provided by extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

Answer (score 5):

I am posting an answer based on my last comment.

Apparently the logic you require -- autoconverting URI from `@RequestParam` to a repository-managed entity -- is implemented in a few private methods of `RepositorySearchController` (see `executeQueryMethod` and `prepareUris`), so there's no easy way to get it in custom controllers.

You can try creating your own argument resolver with Spring HATEOAS. Look into how `PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` resolver is implemented. It resolved an entity based on its `@BackendId`.

Comment: Isn't there a complete working example of that? Should the controller ask for a myEntity parameter or a URI parameter? Thanks